# Add labels to X axis

Tags: r, plot

I made a plot and it turned out fine besides the X axis labels. I want all the labels to be shown on the plot and for some reason the plot only shows some of them.

Following my code:

```
plot(seq(2001,2015,1), sunday_mean, pch=16,
     main="Mean values for all the roads going in Beer Sheva",
     xlab="Year",
     ylab="Appearences")`
```

And here, the plot I get:
[image: my plot]

Answer (score 1):

Check out `axis` to mess with the tick marks/labels.

```
sunday_mean <- rnorm(15, 13) + cumsum(rnorm(15,-0.05))

plot(seq(2001,2015,1), sunday_mean, pch=16,
     main="Mean values for all the roads going in Beer Sheva",
     xlab="Year",
     ylab="Appearences")

axis(1, at=(x=seq(2001,2015,1)), label=paste(x))
```

[image]